# Skip navigation across multiple pages loaded in iframe

Tags: navigation, accessibility, hyperlink, skip

I want to implement skip navigation links in my page. All this skip navigation links are at the top of the page. Page contains an iframes which loads main content.

What i want is when user clicks on "Skip to main content" link at  the top of the page, the focus should be set on particular element that is inside iframe.

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function skipToMainContent() {
var frameElement = document.getElementById("frameElementId");
// replace with your frame's id

var frameDoc = frameElement.contentWindow.document || frameEle.contentDocument;

frameDoc.getElementById("idOfElementToFocusOn").focus();
// replace with your element's id

}
</script>

...

<a href="#idOfIframe" onclick="skipToMainContent()">Skip to main content</a>
```

Is this what you're asking for? That's what I understood from your  question though the subject seems to suggest something else (?).

**Reference**: http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/